# Binding Collection List to grid view

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have a class as follows. I have set the values for each property

```
public class SiteView
{
    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    [DataMember]
    public List<Sites> Site { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    [DataMember]
    public List<SiteDetails> Sitedetails { get; set; }
}

public class Site
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class SiteDetails
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Address { get; set; }
}
```

I have populated the above class with all the values from the database.

i have got the data in List with multiple records. Also the inner list within the class  has multiple records loaded in it.

My question is how do i bind the data to the gridview in asp.net
I want to display the value of name in one of the column in the gridview.
How do i implement it?

Guys please help !!

I tried using

```
<asp:BoundField HeaderText="Name" DataField="SitesView.Sites.Name" />
```

but no success..

Comment: what data source did you pass into your gridview?

Comment: I passed List<SiteView>
I need to display the Name and address in the grid view. There can be multiple records.

Comment: OK. 2 options here - 1) use combined names as a string, e.g. comma separated  2) use nested gridview so you have a child level view can be bound to List<Site>

Comment: Nope i cant use nested grid view and also cant combine the string.

if Site was just a class instead of List<Sites> then i could have access in the boundfields as Site.Name
But being a List<Site> i am not able to access Site.Name. Is there any way to access the List object.?

Comment: You have this reveresed I think: `[DataMember]
    public List<Sites> Site { get; set; }` should be [DataMember]
    public List<Site> Sites { get; set; }

Comment: Not sure why you can't use either of above suggestions. What's your requirement by the way?

Comment: and for clarity you should probably make this change as well:`[DataMember]
    public List<SiteDetail> Sitedetails { get; set; }` : change the class name to `SiteDetail`

Comment: ooops it was just a typo error.
consider
[DataMember]
    public List<Site> Site { get; set; }

Comment: The class structure you have defined says *for each SiteView in List<SiteView> has multiple Sites **and** multiple SiteDetails*  Are you sure that is what you want?  Or should each SiteView contain exactly one Site and SiteDetail?

Comment: Yes for each SiteView in List<SiteView> has multiple Sites and multiple SiteDetails 

Also, the count of records in Sites and SiteDetails will be same

Comment: As it stands right now, and as Woody originally suggested, you are trying to bind a `List<SiteView> SiteViews` to a GridView to to display another List, `List<Site> Sites`  which means nested Gridviews. If you want one GridView that only displays a List<> of Site names then you are going to have to do some work in the code behind to generate a new `List<String> SiteNames` by looping through your data an pulling out the relevent values.

Comment: Have you tried using gridView_RowDataBound event??

Comment: Hi Thanks all for your suggestion.
instead i created another custome class with the required properties and populated the grid.